# How to make symbolic links in FUSE?

Tags: c, programming-languages, fuse

I'm developing a FUSE app that takes a directory with mp3's and mounts a filesystem in another  directory with the following structure (according to their tag's):

```
    Artist1
       |
       -----> Album11
                 |
                 -----> Track01
                 -----> Track02
                 -----> Track03
                 -----> Track04
                 -----> Track05
       -----> Album12
       ....
    Artist2
       |
       -----> Album21
       -----> Album22
       ....
    Artist3
    .....
```

I'm using a sqlite3 database to mantain the links to the real files. The artists and albums elements are folders, and the tracks elements are links to the real ones.

I have achieved to create the folders for the artists and the albums. But now I have a problem.

I have this:

```
  static int getattr(...) {

      ....
      else if ( level == 0  || level == 1 || level == 2 )
      {
          // Estamos en el primer nivel. Son artistas, y por lo tanto, carpetas.
          stbuf->st_mode = S_IFDIR | 0755;
          stbuf->st_nlink = 2;
          lstat(path, stbuf);
      }
      else if (level == 3) {
      // Estamos en el tercer nivel. Son canciones, por lo que son enlaces
      stbuf->st_mode = S_IFLNK | 0755;
      stbuf->st_nlink = 2;
      lstat(path, stbuf);
      }

      .....
  }
```

And now, When I ls in the tracks directory y get a message that tells me that the function is not implemented (the links functions). Which function do I have to implement to know where the link points? Or where do I have to fill the direction of the pointer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work for me:

1. Add a `int my_readlink(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size)` function, which your `struct fuse_operations` member [`.readlink`](http://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html#a0a7fe4e7fe5db55e96ef6adaf64c09e2) should point to. For the symbolic link path, your function should fill the buffer `buf` with a zero-terminated string which is the path of the link target. Don't write more than `size` bytes. E.g. do something like:

   ```
   strncpy(buf, "/target/path", size);
   ```
2. In your `my_getattr()` function (which `struct fuse_operations` member [`.getattr`](http://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html#ac39a0b7125a0e5001eb5ff42e05faa5d) should point to), for the symbolic link path, set in the 2nd parameter (`struct stat * stbuf`):

   - `stbuf->st_mod` to `S_IFLNK | 0777`
   - `stbuf->st_nlink` to `1`
   - `stbuf->st_size` to the length of the target path (don't include the string's zero terminator in the length)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a `readdir` function, see:

[libfuse: fuse_operations Struct Reference](http://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html)

Comment: It's implemented but I don't know how to implement it to link to the desire files

Answer (score 1):

To implement symbolic links, you need to implement the `readlink()` function - you fill a supplied buffer with a null-terminated string that is the target of the link.